# ASP.NET Impersonation To Open a File Share

Tags: c#, asp.net, impersonation

I am trying to impersonation a user in my C# code to open a file share in Windows Explorer. BUT IT IS NOT WORKING! My code is below.

```
Impersonator i = new Impersonator();

using (new Impersonator("userA", "domainA", "pa$$word", LogonType.LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE, LogonProvider.LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT))
{
    Process.Start(@"c:\windows\explorer.exe", @"\\fileshare\abc");
    Response.Write("Impersonated User: " + WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name + "<br />"); 
    Response.Write("Logon User: " + Request.ServerVariables["LOGON_USER"] + "<br />"); 
    Response.Write("Authenticated User: " + Request.ServerVariables["AUTH_USER"] + "<br />") 
}
```

I am using the code to do the impersonation from this site:

http://platinumdogs.wordpress.com/2008/10/30/net-c-impersonation-with-network-credentials/

I am thinking it is because the Logon & Authenticated is my windows login because I am using Windows Authentication?

The account I am impersonating is a domain account and has full account to the file share.

Please help

ADDITIONAL:

I also tried using this code but it did not work. I got an "Access Denied" error

```
string target = "'_blank'";
string script = "window.open(" + @"'file://fileshare/abc'" + "," + target + "," + "'status=no, menubar=yes, toolbar=yes');";
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "someUniqueId", script, true);
```

Comment: Are you planning to process this file server side? (in which case you should use System.IO) or client side (which is sort of an unusual scenario and you would use JScript and ActiveX objects, which will not run in on all machines and will yeild a lot of security warnings)

Comment: All I want to do is open up a window to the folder so they can add files to the folder

Comment: Even if you could disable all security to allow your `window.open` to work, it wouldn't open an explorer window, it would just browse the folder your specified, so you'd see a list of files in your borwser.  That's it.  You couldn't copy files to it.

Comment: re: Yes, the JScript thing is exactly the solution to what you initially asked for (although I image there must be a better soln to whatever you're trying to solve) and you got the security troubles I warned about. To go further, you'd need to start disabling security or getting your browser to trust your code.

Answer (score 1):

You can't start Explorer from an asp.net worker process.  Explorer is a GUI application that requires a WindowStation to display.

When you say "it doesn't work", do you mean explorer doesn't open up when you go to the web page?

Comment: Ok. That makes sense. I tried to use JS to open an IE window but that did not work either.

Comment: @user1034458 - You have to realize that there is a fundamental difference between what you see in the browser and what happens on the server.  They are seperate things.  If you impersonate a user on the server, that doesn't do anything in your web browser.

Comment: All I want to do is open up the folder and allow users to drop files in it.

Comment: @user1034458 - You can't.  It just doesn't work that way.  Web browsers only get HTML markup from the server.  They can't directly access files or folders on the server.

Comment: This is an internal web application. You are saying that I cannot open a domain file share?

Comment: @user1034458 - You can create a file share to the server, sure.  But you can't do it through a web page.  What you do in a webpage happens ON THE SERVER, not on your local client.  Web browsers are prohibited by security mechanisms from accessing local files in most cases.